# Adding picture boxes dynamically to windows form

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am trying add picture boxes dynamically. My code is as

```
PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "pictureBox",
            Size = new Size(100, 150),
            Location = new Point(14, 17),
            Visible=true
        };

        picture.ImageLocation = @"Image\80knhk00003.jpg";
        pnlDisplayImage.Controls.Add(picture);
```

I have created Images Folder in project and added this image. Still when I run my code I can see only red cross.

I tried doing google. And I am getting similar solutions only.
I dont know what is wrong in my code.

Along with this if I am storing image file location in database then how can I display such images in picture box?
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You picture doesn't get copied to the binary folder.

Add the jpg file into the solution. Open it properties (right click on the file name - properties). Enable the Copy to Output Directory option. Also enable it for the Images folder.

Comment: Ok..thanks..this helped along with changing file location in code as: "..\Images\80knhk00003.jpg". But if I have stored file locations in sql database and I want to show these images in picture box how can I do it?

Comment: @user1181942: If the database contains the full path to the image you can just use that. The problem is that `@"Image\80knnk00003.jpg"` refers to a folder `Image` that needs to exist in the same folder as the executable.

Comment: @user1181942 Mark this post as question answer then